# Java Https Post to Api Issue

Tags: java, php, laravel, https

I've changed my PHP Laravel backend to Https and now my java client software can't upload files anymore. My certificate handle works fine and my Https Post request works and get response code 200 but the file doesn't get in the database.
Here my code snippets from

Client (working on Http):

```
Http post = new HttpPost(targetUrl);
MultipartEntityBuilder eb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
int counter = 0;
for (File file : files) {
    LogMe.debug(CloudCommunicator.class, ">> " + file.getName());
    eb.addBinaryBody("" + counter, file);
    counter++;
}
post.setEntity(eb.build());

CloseableHttpResponse response = this.client.execute(post);
httpStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, "UTF-8");
response.close();
```

Client (working not for Https)

```
  httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(targetUrl).openConnection();

  MultipartEntityBuilder eb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
  int counter = 0;
  for (File file : files) {
    LogMe.debug(CloudCommunicator.class, ">> " + file.getName());
    eb.addBinaryBody("" + counter, file);
    counter++;
  }
  HttpEntity httpEntity = eb.build();
  // String query = FsCommunicator.parseObjAsJson(requestData);
  httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(httpEntity.getContentLength()));
  httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType.toString());
  //httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
  httpsConnection.setDoOutput(true);
  httpsConnection.setDoInput(true);
  httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "token=" + msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue());
  //DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(httpsConnection.getOutputStream());

  httpEntity.writeTo(httpsConnection.getOutputStream());
  while (httpEntity.isStreaming()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
  httpsConnection.getOutputStream().flush();
  httpsConnection.getOutputStream().close();
```

Testing my API under Https with Postman was successfully. The problem have to be on the java client side. Have got anybody an idea, please?
      httpStatusCode = httpsConnection.getResponseCode();

**Solution:**

```
try {
      KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
      trustStore.load(null);// Make an empty store
      InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FsCommunicator.getResource("binary/xixLab.crt"));
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

      CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

      while (bis.available() > 0) {
        java.security.cert.Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("fiddler" + bis.available(), cert);
      }
      sslcontext.loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());

      client = HttpClients.custom().setSslcontext(sslcontext.build()).setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
          .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```

Comment: can you please post what error you are getting ?

Comment: Laravel write no error in his log file and java not throwing any exceptions.